# Automatically Sized bra/ket in Quantum Physics

Tags: braket

I got to know that `\left` and `\right` allow us to automatically adjust the sizes of brackets. I'm currently working on some documents of Quantum Physics with so-called Dirac notations of bra and ket, made of `\langle`, `|` and `\rangle`.

Typically, there are 5 types of combinations: `|a>`, `<b|`, `<a>`, `<a|b>` and `<a|c|b>`. It is easy to use `\left` and `\right` for the first 3 types, how can I make automatic adjustment for all the symbols?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you know [the `braket` package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/braket/braket.pdf)?

Comment: @egreg, thanks! I'm wondering how this implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `braket`, where the commands `\bra`, `\ket` and `\braket` have the “automatic extended” variants `\Bra`, `\Ket` and `\Braket`.

Or you can make your own commands. Here each of the `\bra`, `\ket` and `\braket` command accepts an optional size argument (`\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`), or a `*` for the automatically extensible version.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,xparse}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\bra}[1]{\langle}{\rvert}{#1\,}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\ket}[1]{\lvert}{\rangle}{\,#1}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\makebraket}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1}

\NewDocumentCommand{\braket}{som}{%
  \begingroup\activatebraketbar
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\makebraket*{#3}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}{\makebraket{#3}}{\makebraket[#2]{#3}}}%
  \endgroup
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\braketbar}{%
  \,\delimsize\vert\@ifnextchar|{\!}{\,}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\activatebraketbar}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`|\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\braketbar
  \mathcode`|="8000
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\bra{x}+\ket{\psi(t)}+
\bra[\big]{x}+\ket[\big]{\psi(t)}+
\bra[\Big]{x}+\ket[\Big]{\psi(t)} \\
\braket{x|\psi(t)}\quad\braket{x|y|\psi(t)} \\
\braket[\big]{x|\psi(t)}\quad\braket[\big]{x|y|\psi(t)} \\
\braket[\Big]{x|\psi(t)}\quad\braket[\Big]{x|y|\psi(t)} \\
\braket*{\frac{x}{y}|z}+\braket*{x|\frac{a}{b}|z} \\
\braket{a||b}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The use of `\middle` can help here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\def\z{\frac{x}{y}}
\[
\left\lvert\z\right\rangle\quad
\left\langle\z\right\rvert\quad
\left\langle\z\right\rangle\quad
\left\langle\z\middle\vert b\right\rangle\quad
\left\langle\z\middle\vert b\middle\vert c\right\rangle
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package `physics` has few commands for this purpose.

1. `\bra`

[image]

```
\[\bra{a} \quad \bra{\frac{a}{b}} \quad \bra*{\frac{a}{b}}\]
```

2. `\ket`

[image]

```
\[\ket{b} \quad \ket{\frac{a}{b}} \quad \ket*{\frac{a}{b}}\]
```

3. `\braket`

[image]

```
\[\braket{a}{b} \quad \braket{a}{\frac{x}{y}} \quad \braket*{a}{\frac{x}{y}}\]
```

4. `\expectationvalue` or `\ev`

[image]

```
\[\ev{a} \quad \ev{H}{a}\]
```

5. `\matrixelement` or `\mel`

[image]

```
\[\mel{a}{H}{b}  \quad \mel{a}{\hat{H}}{b} \quad \mel**{a}{\hat{H}}{b}\]
```

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}

\begin{document}
\[\bra{a} \quad \bra{\frac{a}{b}} \quad \bra*{\frac{a}{b}} \]
\[\ket{b} \quad \ket{\frac{a}{b}} \quad \ket*{\frac{a}{b}} \]
\[\braket{a}{b} \quad \braket{a}{\frac{x}{y}} \quad \braket*{a}{\frac{x}{y}}\]
\[\ev{a} \quad \ev{H}{a}\]
\[\mel{a}{H}{b}  \quad \mel{a}{\hat{H}}{b} \quad \mel**{a}{\hat{H}}{b}\]
\end{document}
```