# Why does esint clash when I include it in my package?

Tags: package-writing, mathtools, physics, esint

I am trying to write my own package, but I can not include `esint` without getting errors.
Here is an MWE of my package:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{zyy}[2021/08/14 Yiyu's preamble for article]

\RequirePackage[e]{esvect} %% stylish vector symbols
\RequirePackage{esint} %% various integral symbols

\RequirePackage{tensor} %% manage order of tensor indices
\RequirePackage{slashed} %% Feynman slash notation
\RequirePackage{simpler-wick} %% Wick contraction
\RequirePackage{physics}

\RequirePackage{amssymb} %% this package loads package 'amsfonts' internally

\numberwithin{equation}{section} %% number equations by section and subsection numbers

\RequirePackage{mathtools} %% a more powerful version of package 'amsmath'
```

Unless I comment out `physics`, `\numberwith` and `mathtools`, the inclusion of `esint` will cause conflicts during typesetting:

```bash
! LaTeX Error: Command \iint already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

But I have checked, neither `physics` nor `mathtools` defines `\iint`.

---

To make things more mysterious, if I comment out `\RequirePackage{esint}` in my `.sty` file, and instead include it from the document, everything will be fine:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zyy}
\usepackage{esint}

\begin{document}
$\oint$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `mathtools` loads `amsmath` that *does* define `\iint`.

Comment: I don't have time to look at this properly now, but what happens if you put `\RequirePackage{esint}` after `\RequirePackage{mathtools}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the loading order: `esint` has to go after `amsmath` (which is loaded by `mathtools`). The documentation of `esint` still mentions `amslatex`, but it should be interpreted as `amsmath`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{zyy}[2021/08/14 Yiyu's preamble for article]

\RequirePackage{mathtools} %% a more powerful version of package 'amsmath'
\RequirePackage{amssymb} %% this package loads package 'amsfonts' internally
\RequirePackage[e]{esvect} %% stylish vector symbols
\RequirePackage{esint} %% various integral symbols

\RequirePackage{tensor} %% manage order of tensor indices
\RequirePackage{slashed} %% Feynman slash notation
\RequirePackage{simpler-wick} %% Wick contraction
\RequirePackage{physics}


\counterwithin{equation}{section} %% number equations by section and subsection numbers
```

I changed `\numberwithin` into `\counterwithin` that's the kernel version.

Aside note: are you sure you want to load `physics`? I wouldn't. It seems to provide bells and whistles, but at the expense of clumsy syntax and disputable output.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! As for the `physics` package, it provides Dirac bra-ket notations that can be very handy.

Comment: @zyy It's not unique in that respect. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/483996/4427

Comment: That looks nice, thank you!